# Leaflet L.geoJSON drag able

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

Hello i am doing drag able functionality each shape. The drag able functionality move success but selected geometry shape or marker not remove. The problem create edit case

```
var polygon = L.polygon(latlngs, { color: "red", draggable: true }).addTo(map);

L.geoJSON(data, {
  style: polystyle
})
  .bindPopup(function(layer) {
    var marker = L.marker(layer.getLatLng(), {
      color: "red",
      draggable: true
    }).addTo(map);

    marker.on("dragend", function(e) {
      var newMarker = e.target;
      var position = newMarker.getLatLng();
      map.panTo(new L.LatLng(position.lat, position.lng));
      newMarker
        .setLatLng(position, {
          draggable: "true"
        })
        .bindPopup(position)
        .update();
      map.addLayer(newMarker);
    });
  })
  .addTo(map);
```

Data variable store is different shape.

Comment: You're adding markers to the map on some user interactions, but they are never removed. What is that you're trying to achieve here, *exactly*?

Comment: @IvanSanchez   screen shot https://prnt.sc/nopih7 and code is https://textuploader.com/1dk0u shape is copies generate previous not remove own location

Answer (score 1):

you are using two times variable declare
    var drawnItems = L.geoJSON(data, {}); 
only one time declare

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code duplicate value repeat

```
L.geoJSON(data, {
style: polystyle
})
.bindPopup(function(layer) {
var marker = L.marker(layer.getLatLng(), {
color: "red",
draggable: true
}).addTo(map);
```